# Want to change icon as the theme apply on device

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I am trying launcher for android device, I want to add the themes and styles, applying these themes icon of the app should change same as every launcher provides. if anyone can help . Thank you.

Comment: All the icons of the App or any specific icon ?

Comment: All app icon on device

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358 look at point number 7 there is way to put your own icon

Comment: Thanks for support , i already apply this, this is not what i am asking for , i want to change it every time as the user change theme every time.

Comment: ohk most welcome :) ;)